# Switching CNN layers with RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

If I have these layers for a CNN

```py
img_shape = (256, 256, 3)
model = keras.Sequential(name='RGBimg_Classify_Net')
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(
    128, 3, input_shape=(img_shape), activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D())
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, strides=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D())
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, strides=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D())
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(len(classes), activation='softmax'))
```

What can I do to keep as many things as constant but to switch the main neural network to recurrent neural network?

Comment: What kind of sequence are you trying to predict and what's the motivation behind converting this CNN into an RNN. It's more likely to get help when you explain more and provide examples.

Comment: @HakanAkgün I am trying to predict imagery data and switching from CNN to RNN is just for testing how RNN would work with the same data... Sorry I am   new to this any advice would be appreciated

Comment: RNNs are usually used for sequence prediction switching from CNN to RNN didn't make sense to me.

Comment: As rightly mentioned by @HakanAkgün there is no benefit in switching. In general, `CNN's` employ filters within convolutional layers to transform data. Whereas as `RNN's` reuse activation functions from other data points in the sequence to generate the next output in a series. For more information you can refer [this](https://www.telusinternational.com/articles/difference-between-cnn-and-rnn) article. Thanks!